# How can I force CMake to use the correct OpenCV version?

Tags: python, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to run a python script that uses a custom module written by someone else. I created that module by running CMake according to the creator's instructions. Running my python script, I get the error: `ImportError: libopencv_imgproc.so.3.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. This error is caused by the module I created earlier.
There is no file of that name since I have OpenCV 3.2.0 installed, so in usr/local/lib there's libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2.0. I don't know how to fix this or where to start looking. The CMakeLists.txt of the module has a line

`find_package(OpenCV 3 COMPONENTS core highgui imgproc REQUIRED)`.

I tried changing it to

`find_package(OpenCV 3.2.0 COMPONENTS core highgui imgproc REQUIRED)`,

without success.

Comment: Try with `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)` ?

Comment: This doesn't add up -- how did the module get linked with a library that's not there in the first place?

Comment: `find_package()` works in mysterious ways. Could you try `locate libopencv_imgproc.so.3.1`, just to be sure there is no such library?

Comment: `locate libopencv_imgproc.so.3.1` didn't find anything. However come to think of it, OpenCV 3.1 was installed on this machine before, but for another user. Maybe it wasn't removed thoroughly? I checked the CMake output during build: `-- Found OpenCV: /usr/local (found version "3.2.0") found components:  core highgui imgproc`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an old version of the module lurking an a different folder where the python script was actually looking. This must have been created in the past with an OpenCV 3.1 environment.